# uniform initialization for dynamic objects

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, unique-ptr, uniform-initialization

```
#include <memory>

struct foo
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
};

int main()
{
    foo bar { std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42)) };
    // okay

    new foo { std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42)) };
    // error: no matching function for call to
    // 'foo::foo(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
}
```

Does uniform initialization not work with dynamic objects, or is this a shortcoming of g++ 4.6.1?

---

It works with g++ 4.7.1, but **both lines** in `main` fail to compile if `foo` inherits from another class:

```
struct baz
{
    // no data members, just some member functions
};

struct foo : baz
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
};
```

Again, shortcoming of my compiler? Or does uniform initialization not play well with inheritance?

Comment: `new foo ({std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42))});` This works with 4.6.1

Comment: @jrok Does that mean the syntax I used is (without the additional parenthesis) somehow inferior, non-idiomatic or even "wrong"?

Comment: There was a similar question a while ago, but I can't find it. IIRC, the conclusion was it's a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It builds fine with g++-4.7. So presumably the latter. I'll have a look to see if I can find stronger evidence via the docs.

**And in response to the inheritance addendum:**

This simpler case also fails to compile:

```
struct baz
{
};

struct foo : baz
{
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    foo bar { 12 };
}
```

With:

```
testoo.cpp:14:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo::foo(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
testoo.cpp:14:18: note: candidates are:
testoo.cpp:7:8: note: foo::foo()
testoo.cpp:7:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
testoo.cpp:7:8: note: constexpr foo::foo(const foo&)
testoo.cpp:7:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const foo&’
testoo.cpp:7:8: note: constexpr foo::foo(foo&&)
testoo.cpp:7:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘foo&&’
```

According to my reading of the standard, you have been getting `aggregate initialization` in your first example:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equal- initializers for non-static
>   data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).
>
> When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as specified
>   in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list  are taken as
>   initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript
>   or member order.

Note that this explicitly forbids base classes. So to sum up - aggregate initialization is not allowed in the presence of base classes. And hence neither of the second examples will compile.

Comment: Theoretically this could be a regression. But yes, not likely.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Good point. I'm trying to find some documentation about this in the g++ release notes, but so far to no avail.

Comment: @Alex I've added another twist to my question in case you're interested ;)

Comment: @FredOverflow: I have parsed the standard to the best of my ability, and come up with an answer... :-)

Answer (score 2):

> **both lines** in `main` fail to compile if `foo` inherits from another class

Ah, uniform initialization works differently for aggregates and non-aggregates:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - If T is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered
>
> An aggregate is [..] a class [...] with no base classes [...] and no virtual functions.

So I still have to write custom constructors in my case, since I need the subtype polymorphism here.

Comment: so, list initialization & uniform initialization both the terms are same. They aren't different. right?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the final version in hand at the moment, but draft N3242, `§ 8.5.4 List-initialization` explicitly states that list-initialization can be used as the initializer in a new expression.  It also provides the following example:

```
new std::vector<std::string>{"once", "upon", "a", "time"}; // 4 string elements
```